# Dump database from Datagrip using 'mysqldump'

Tags: mysql, docker, datagrid

I want to export my database from `Datagrip` to a single `.sql` file using `mysqldump` feature. All it needs is to provide `mysqldump` execution path but I haven't installed `mysql-client` directly on my local machine (`mysqldump` command not found), I using `Docker` container instead.
Do I have to install `mysql-client` to use this feature?

Comment: `mysqldump` will be installed within the container if that helps.

Comment: How can I using `mysqldump` from the host machine without go inside the container?

Comment: You can't without go inside the container. Yes, you need the mysql-client package to get `mysqldump`. You can't execute programs that aren't installed.

Comment: Without Datagrip you can do `docker exec -it <container-name> mysqldump`, but if you enter that as the command in the Datagrip Export dialogue it complains that "path to executable is wrong", even if you use the full path to the `docker` executable ...  Anyone managed to get this working?